# Bind an externally loaded DOM element to Angular's scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm using Google Maps within an Angular app. As per Google Maps's API, I pass a `string` to a `google.maps` function containing HTML, and the library displays it on the map as an InfoView.

I'm adding a button to this view, and I want this view to be bound to a controller in my Angular app, however, even if I pass `<div ng-controller="MyController">...</div>`, when the Maps library attaches it to the DOM, Angular is not notified.

How can I force the compilation of this element (over which I have very little control: just passing a string)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For AngularJS to "notice" the directive, it'd need to compile the element, which is not done automatically except when bootstrapping the application. So either the API needs to allow you to pass DOM `Element` to it (and you need to `$compile` and link it before you pass it on), or you need to find the element after it is added to DOM and then `$compile` and link it. AFAIK, if you cannot do either of those, then what you're asking is impossible.

---

If you manage to get hold of the element, [compiling it](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) is as simple as calling

```
$compile(element)($scope);
```

where `$scope` is the scope you want to link it to (possibly even `$rootScope`).

Comment: I've tried the first one and it won't let me pass DOM elements. How would you go about the second one? I think I can find the added element easily. Then what?

Comment: I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: I made it work, but had to add a setTimeout to the $compile to tamper until the element got available