# Apply $compile and $scope to external div text moved into ng-view element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a `div` element that I attach to one of the elements within an `ng-view` DOM tree. The `div` contains text elements which I'd like to have evaluated within the current `$scope` of the `ng-view` tree. How do I get Angular to re-evaluate the attached element within that scope?

The `div` element exists initially in a separate part of the document, outside of the `ng-view` element, and looks something like this:

```
<div id="eventInfo">
  The event takes place at {{eventModel.startTime}}.
</div>
```

I need the `eventModel.startTime` expression to get bound with respect to the scope of the element within the `ng-view` that I'm moving it into, where its scope contains the correct instance of the `eventModel` object.

I think I need to do something along these lines:

```
targetDiv.appendChild(eventInfo);      // Move event text into target element
var scope = angular.element(targetDiv).scope();    // Get target scope
angular.$compile(eventInfo)(scope);    // (?) Apply target scope to event text
```

The problem is the last line. This JS code is not within an Angular controller, so how do I get access to `$compile`?

(I've looked at question "[Bind an externally loaded DOM element to Angular's scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110875)" already, but it does not answer my question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to get the `$compile` service from the app [injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector).

Assuming your ng-app is on the html level, or you manually bootstrapped the app with document as the rootElement you would do (otherwise select which ever is the root element instead of document):

```
var $compile = angular.element(document).injector().get('$compile');
$compile(eventInfo)(scope);
scope.$apply();
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. I will note that the re-evaluated text items within the moved `div` element should be `<span ng-bind="expr">` instead of `{{expr}}`, otherwise you can move and `$apply` the scope to the `div` only once.